# How to group things what are not in a specific range in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

Doing revision for a SQL test I've got coming up and I'm having issues finding a query to meet one of the requirements of the questions. Heres the question:

9. The HR department needs to find the high-salary and low-salary employees. Modify your query from (7) to display the last name and salary for all employees whose salary is not in the range 5,000 through 12,000

Here's what I've got:

```sql
SELECT last_name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary BETWEEN 5000 AND 12000;
```

When I execute the query I get all of the employees who land between those 2 values, I need the employees who land outside of the range of the 2 values. Do I need to use '<' '>'?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Simply add a `NOT`. But of course you can also use less than and greater than comparisons: `WHERE salary < 5000 OR salary > 12000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT last_name, salary 
FROM employees 
WHERE salary NOT BETWEEN 5000 AND 12000
```